# Win32 API: process WM_* in tab control's wndproc instead of parent's

Tags: c, winapi

Currently I have a tab control attached to a main window on my program.

However, when I switch tabs, the `WM_NOTIFY` messages are sent to the parent of the tab control, not to the tab control itself.

Is there a way to make the tab control's WndProc receive and process those messages instead of the parent?

I'm using the raw win32 C API. No MFC or any kind of libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

**1. Subclassing**

You can [subclass the tab control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx) so you *can* handle messages there in the first place, then in your parent window have some code like

```
#define msgNOTIFY (WM_APP + 0x40)
// ...
case WM_NOTIFY:
    return SendMessageW(nm->hwndFrom, msgNOTIFY, wParam, lParam);
```

which will bounce the `WM_NOTIFY` back. Same for `WM_COMMAND`. I used a separate message ID for this redirected `WM_NOTIFY`/`WM_COMMAND` to be safe; you might not have to (I don't know for sure). [If your controls move between windows, you'll also have to do this from all windows.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/16/9979112.aspx)

**2. Use a Middleman**

Instead of placing the tab control directly on your window, place it inside another control (preferably one of your own creation, which does nothing but be sized to fit the child) that you place on your window instead, and handle messages there. This has the advantage of avoiding the reparenting issue linked above, but [costs a window handle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/07/18/3926581.aspx), so I normally don't suggest doing so. It does work, though. And if you do this for your tab pages, switching pages is as easy as hiding one control and showing another! (In fact, this is what property sheets do with their child dialogs.)

Comment: thanks, but I can't really change the parent's wndproc, which is why I'm trying to process the messages in the tab control instead of the parent.

Comment: Can you not subclass the parent instead then?

Comment: that's what I was trying to say (I may have expressed myself the wrong way). I cannot subclass it, or rather, I must not. So I'm trying to find a way of doing it without subclassing.

Comment: The only other option is to put the tab control inside some other control and put *that* inside your parent window. I don't know if the tab control responds well to reparenting, but it's unlikely that it wouldn't...

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that did the trick. I'm not sure, but can you use that as an answer? I'd accept it.